# -[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, delegates

I have passed an NSArray value back to a parent view using a delegate.

it is received in the parent view like so

```
- (void) setManufactureSearchFields:(NSArray *)arrayValues withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)myIndexPath
{
    manufactureSearchObjectString = [arrayValues valueForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"];
    NSLog(@"%@",[arrayValues valueForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"]);
    manufactureResultIndexPath = myIndexPath;
    [self.tableView reloadData]; //reloads the tabels so you can see the value in the tableViewCell.
}
```

If i was to execute this code and select the tablecell of the childview it obviously executes the delegate but then freezes up and fires this error to the Log

```
2011-10-31 14:06:16.670 code[12610:207] (
    "Alfa Romeo"
)
2011-10-31 14:06:16.673 code[12610:207] *** -[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6859280
```

However if I comment out the following line in my delegate method

```
   - (void) setManufactureSearchFields:(NSArray *)arrayValues withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)myIndexPath
    {
        //manufactureSearchObjectString = [arrayValues valueForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"];
        NSLog(@"%@",[arrayValues valueForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"]);
        manufactureResultIndexPath = myIndexPath;
        [self.tableView reloadData]; //reloads the tabels so you can see the value in the tableViewCell.
    }
```

it dose not crash and I end up with the NSLog with the correct details in my log like so.

```
2011-10-31 14:09:28.200 code[12737:207] (
    Sony
)
```

I am hoping someone has experianced such a problem before, this is what my array object looks like, its a dictionary of values.

```
ISELECT = F;
ISALIVE = T;
MANUFACTURER = Sony;
MANUFACTURERID = 3;
```

Comment: One of your keys isn't.  It's been deallocated since you did too many releases on it.

Comment: There might be a problem with other parts of your code. Did you use manufactureSearchObjectString any where else?

Comment: yea I am thinking the same thing as now the error is showing up where I am passing the value over to a uilabel like so **label2.text = manufactureSearchObjectString;** which I am sure is wrong but not sure how to fix, as I'm trying to put an array into a text value i think i need to do isequaltostring or something?

Comment: I think you should first access to an object of the array and then use the valueForKey: method in order to get first the NSDictionary with your values and then access to the right object; something like     manufactureSearchObjectString = [[arrayValues objectAtIndex:myIndexPath.row] objectForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"];. Hope this helps.

Comment: ISELECT = F;
ISALIVE = T;
MANUFACTURER = Sony;
MANUFACTURERID = 3; is ones array object so I dont need to use the indexPath. the indexpath value I have there is to resign a accessory tick into the subview (last selection) in case the user would like to change it.

Answer (score 1):

`valueForKey:` returns an autoreleased instance. Unless you retain it, you can expect it will be deallocated sometime after you return from the current method. It looks like you are assigning it to an instance variable. If you do that, you need to retain it.

```
manufactureSearchObjectString = [arrayValues valueForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"];
[manufactureSearchObjectString retain];
```

But it looks like you have another problem.

```
[arrayValues valueForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"];
```

That returns an array.

```
manufactureSearchObjectString = [arrayValues valueForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"];
```

By the name of your variable, it looks as though you're assigning it to a string variable. So if you fix the retain issue, then you will have another error. You will get an unrecognized selector when you try to call isEqualToString on it.

You need to assign a string value to manufactureSearchObjectString. You need to figure out what string value you want that to be. In this case you only have one string in your array, so I guess you want that one. In that case

```
manufactureSearchObjectString = [[arrayValues valueForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"] objectAtIndex:0];
[manufactureSearchObjectString retain];
```

But in general you need to check if there is more than one value in the array, and decide which one you want, and also check if there are no values in the array, and do something correct to handle that.

Comment: cool cheers, I checked to see if it works and it dose however I'm going to take your comments into consideration and do abit more reading on this. at least for now though I know its possible to do what I am trying to achieve just need to clean it up abit.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code into this:

```
- (void) setManufactureSearchFields:(NSDictionary *)arrayValues withIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)myIndexPath
{
    manufactureSearchObjectString = [[arrayValues valueForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"] copy];
    NSLog(@"%@",[arrayValues valueForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"]);
    manufactureResultIndexPath = myIndexPath;
    [self.tableView reloadData]; //reloads the tabels so you can see the value in the tableViewCell.
}
```

Please note that I've also changed the variable type of `arrayValues` to `NSDictionary`. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I am passing it an array value so i couldnt change the to nsdictionary. I tried the copy version of your code and its still got the same error... the thing is however it now highlighted a different part of my code with the error as above. when I set up my textfield label for displaying the manufacture value im going to get i do it like this.. obviously its wrong. but I dont know why.

**label2.text = manufactureSearchObjectString;**

Comment: maybe because im passing it an array value to a string?

Answer (score 0):

please convert it to NSString.

```
 NSString *manufact=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrayValues valueForKey:@"MANUFACTURER"];
```

It will not get crash.